# How to fix a function with original data

Tags: python

```
def check_balance_ATM (operation):
     user = 'admin'
     user_file = user + "_balance.json"
     with open (user_file, "r") as f:
         admin_balance = json.load (f)
     all_money = (sum (int (bancknote) * value for bancknote, value in admin_balance.items ()))
     if operation == "check balance ATM":
         print (f'Total at ATM: {all_money} UAH ',' \ n ')
         print ('The ATM is:')
         for bancknote, value in admin_balance.items ():
             print (f "Banknote {bancknote} UAH - {value} pcs.")
         add_transaction (user, operation, all_money)
     return all_money
```

How to fix a function with original data

```
{"1000": 0, "500": 2, "200": 6, "100": 0, "50": 0, "20": 0, "10": 0}
```

Need to count 1100

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "fixing a function with original data"?

Comment: I have a file json with data {"1000": 0, "500": 2, "200": 6, "100": 0, "50": 0, "20": 0, "10": 0} writes error when I need to count 1100, and if I change the value of "500": 2 to "500": 1 then give 500 + 200 + 200 + 200

Comment: What's the error? What do you mean by "count 1100"? Is `500 + 200 + 200 + 200` incorrect? Why? What's the correct result? What is the `check_balance_ATM` function supposed to do? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The function must sum the notes for output, for example I enter 1100 with the following source data {"1000": 0, "500": 2, "200": 6, "100": 0, "50": 0, "20": 0, "10": 0} I write an error (I need 500 + 200 + 200 + 200), and when I change the value of "" 1000 ": 0," 500 ": 1," 200 ": 6," 100 ": 0, "50": 0, "20": 0, "10": 0} such an operation is done 500 + 200 + 200 + 200 = 1100

Comment: Please add all this explanation to the question itself, rather than squeezing it into a series of comments.